# cudaMalloc global array cause seg fault

Tags: cuda

I found some difficulty when I try to access a global array from function that's executed from device:

```
float globTemp[3][3] = "some value in here";
__device__ float* globTemp_d;

__global__ void compute(int *a, int w)
{
  int x = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x * blockIdx.x;
  int y = threadIdx.y + blockDim.y * blockIdx.y;
  int i = y*w+x;
  if(x<3 && y<3)
    a[i] = 1+globTemp_d[i];
}

int hostFunc(){
   float *a_d;
   cudaMalloc((void**)&a_d, 3*3*sizeof(int));
   cudaMalloc((void**)&globTemp_d, 3*3*sizeof(int));
   cudaMemcpy(globTemp_d,globTemp, 3*3*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
   compute<<<1,1>>>(a_d,3);
   cudaMemcpy(a,a_d, 3*3*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
}
```

However, I get seg fault when i try to access globTemp_d[i]. Am I doing something wrong in here?

Comment: Is globTemp_d ever initialised?

Comment: @Ldrumm I think the cudaMalloc initialize the globTemp_d right?

Comment: Just checked that compiler attribute; looks like I'm getting tired, and probably shouldn't be questioning CUDA.

Comment: No, this code is broken in a variety of ways.  If you do [cuda error checking](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038589/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-errors-using-the-cuda-runtime-api) you'll discover that some of your cuda API calls are failing.  Then if you [read up](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#device-variable-qualifier) on `__device__` variables you'll see that you don't use `cudaMalloc` and `cudaMemcpy`.    It's possible to do something like what you have shown, but why not use ordinary host-based pointers with `cudaMalloc` and `cudaMemcpy`?

Comment: Yes, you aren't use `cudaSafeCall`

Answer (score 1):

There are a variety of problems with your code:

1. Your grid is a 1D grid of 1D threadblocks (in fact you are launching a single block of 1 thread) but your kernel is written as if it were expecting a 2D threadblock structure (using `.x` and `.y` built-in variables).  A single thread won't get the work done certainly, and a 1D threadblock won't work with your kernel code.
2. `__device__` variables are [not accessed](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#device-variable-qualifier) with `cudaMalloc` and `cudaMemcpy`.  We use a different set of API calls like `cudaMemcpyToSymbol`.
3. You're not doing any [cuda error checking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038589/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-errors-using-the-cuda-runtime-api) which is always recommended when you're having difficulty.  You should do cuda error checking on both API calls *and* kernel calls.
4. You're mixing `float` variables (`a_d` ) with `int` variables in the kernel parameters (`int *a`) so I don't think this code would compile without at least a warning.  And that can lead to strange behavior of course if you ignore it.

This is the closest I could come to your code while fixing all the errors:

```
#include <stdio.h>

__device__ float* globTemp_d;

__global__ void compute(float *a, int w)
{
  int x = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x * blockIdx.x;
  int y = threadIdx.y + blockDim.y * blockIdx.y;
  int i = (y*w)+x;
  if((x<3) && (y<3))
    a[i] = 1.0f+globTemp_d[i];
}

int main(){
   float *a_d, *d_globTemp;
   float globTemp[3][3] = {0.1f, 0.2f, 0.3f, 0.4f, 0.5f, 0.6f, 0.7f, 0.8f, 0.9f};
   float a[(3*3)];
   dim3 threads(3,3);
   dim3 blocks(1);
   cudaMalloc((void**)&a_d, 3*3*sizeof(float));
   cudaMalloc((void**)&d_globTemp, 3*3*sizeof(float));
   cudaMemcpy(d_globTemp,globTemp, 3*3*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
   cudaMemcpyToSymbol(globTemp_d, &d_globTemp, sizeof(float *));
   compute<<<blocks,threads>>>(a_d,3);
   cudaMemcpy(a,a_d, 3*3*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

   printf("results:\n");
   for (int i = 0; i<(3*3); i++)
     printf("a[%d] = %f\n", i, a[i]);
   return 0;
}
```

This code can be simplified by dispensing with the `__device__` variable and just passing `d_globTemp` as a parameter to the kernel, and using it in place of references to `globTemp_d`. However I did not make that simplification.